# Q_OBJECT macro issue during build

Tags: c++, qt, macros, premake

I'm working on a project using `QT`. To link it with premake, I cloned the addon which generate a QT solution [premake-qt](https://github.com/dcourtois/premake-qt). It works fine when it comes to use qt in general.
But I need to create custom signals so to do that, I had to add `Q_OBJECT` in my header file.
Here is the file:

```cpp
#pragma once
#ifndef _WINDOW_H_
#define _WINDOW_H_

#include <QApplication>
#include <QWidget>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QProgressBar>
#include <QSlider>
#include <QFileDialog>
#include <QtDebug>
#include <QFile>
#include <QTextStream>
#include <QMenu>

class WindowUI : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

    enum class State {
        Save = 0,
        Export = 1,
    };
... // rest of header
```

So without the `Q_OBJECT` everything works fine, but when I build with it, I have an error.

```
>Moc'ing Window.h
>the specified path cannot be found.
```

And something I found is that it generates a `moc_Window.args` and a `moc_Window.cpp` in the vscode tree but the `.cpp` is not in my work directory.
If needed I can provide my `premake.lua` config file where I link QT if something is missing.
Do I have to run `qmake` on my project when I add `Q_OBJECT` ?
[image: Tree]

Comment: When adding/removing `Q_OBJECT` macro from header, premake should be relaunch.

Comment: *"the specified path cannot be found"* seems to indicate moc.exe is not in the path. (or maybe an issue about special path (space, unicode char, ... ?) ).

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the class from VS project and adding it back. I've had similar issues when changing a normal class to QObject based (including Q_OBJECT macro). I think the issue is related to how the Qt VS add-in does the moc'cing.

Comment: I've tried, still the same error. Did you do something specific with the add-in ? Because I didn't used it to create my project.